# PowerBI data model / relationship

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I am a Newbie and I have a question,

Lets say I have 2 tables named `sales` table and `roster` table.
On the `sales` table there is everything `PID`, `Partner_Name` etc

### Sales Table

| PID | Partner_Name | Some_Column_1 | Some_Column_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| 2 | Company B | Value 3 | Value 4 |
| 3 | Company C | Value 5 | Value 6 |

and on the second table I have `PID`, `Partner_Name` and `PID`, `Partner_type`.

### Roster Table

| PID | Partner_Name | Partner_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company A | Type A |
| 2 | Company B | Type B |
| 3 | Company C | Type C |

I want to get the `Partner_Type` from the `roster` table. If `PID` is not found in the `roster` table else use `Partner_Name` to look the `Partner_Type`.

What will be the data model for this?

Comment: Are you sure yor are looking for `Data Model`  only and not `sql`? Also, this is a very poorly drafted question and does not confrom to forum rules. You are bound to get downvoted.